# Why is my array pointer overflowing the stack?

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, stack-overflow

My C++ program has a very large const array, which should be allocated on the heap, but for some reason it's crashing my stack. It goes something like this:

Foo.h

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

struct Data
{
    short id;
    std::vector<short> points;
    Data(short i, std::vector<short> p) : id(i), points(p) {}
}

class Foo
{
private:
    short id;
    std::vector<Data> data;
public:
    Foo(short i, std::vector<data> d) : id(i), data(d) {}
};
```

ARRAY.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Foo.h"

const int ARRAY_LENGTH = 1058;

static const Foo *ARRAY = new Foo[ARRAY_LENGTH]
{
    Learnset(1, std::vector<Data>({
        Data(1, std::vector<short>({151, 489, 435, 65, 282, 355, 92})),
        Data(8, std::vector<short>({286})),
        Data(19, std::vector<short>({595})),
        Data(26, std::vector<short>({417, 201})),
        [...]
    })),
    [...]
}
```

This array basically serves as a database for the program. I know it's this array causing the overflow because if I comment out most of it, the program runs just fine.

Even stranger is that, when I check using `sizeof`, the program reports that the array is 4 bytes long, just like I would expect it to be, so I think that the program might be trying to build the array on the stack before moving it to the heap, and I'm not sure if my use of vectors is responsible. I have no idea how to correct it.

Comment: You typed out 1058 initializers each with multiple sub-initializers or is this automatically generated code?

Comment: It's not `ARRAY` that's being built on the stack, but the initializer list. This part: `{Data(1...), Data(8...), ...}` I assume the list actually has O(1000) elements.

Comment: Couldn't you add a vardiac template constructor to Foo (and Data) to create the vector in place by forwarding the args and I believe std::vector already has this and everything would get constructed in place?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is causing a stack overflow is because the initializer list for the constructor of `vector<Data>` is going to be constructed on the stack.

When you initialize a namespace-scope static variable, the compiler is going to emit an initialization routine that initializes the variable. In this case, you're using `operator new[]` and providing values with which to initialize the array (I assume `Learnset` should be `Foo`). In order to construct the `Foo` objects the array is initialized with, the routine will have to call the constructor of `Foo`, passing the arguments you provide. Those arguments, in turn, will have to be constructed first (on the stack).

So just to initialize the first element of the array, the compiler will have to create the initializer list of `short`s for the vector (on the stack), construct the vector (on the stack), pass this to the constructor of `Data`, do this for every `Data` object to create the initializer list, then call the vector constructor, etc... This produces an enormous initializer list that lives on the stack, before it's passed to the constructor of `vector<Data>`.

If you're on a truly stack-constrained platform, you may need to make your constructors constexpr or avoid initializing by initializer list, which can consume stack space proportional to its size.

However, why are you using a pointer to dynamically allocate the array instead of just using an array type? If you use `std::array<Foo, ARRAY_LENGTH>` or even `Foo ARRAY[ARRAY_LENGTH]`, the array will just live in the data segment instead of being dynamically allocated. It might even be compile-time evaluated if your constructors are constexpr. If it's not compile-time evaluated, the stack consumption is still a concern.